# JAX-RS filters calling sequence

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs, marshalling, unmarshalling

My implemention of the JAX-RS Filters as as follows,

The request filter is :

```
   public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
        public static long entryTime;
         @Override
            public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                            throws IOException {

             /*some preprocessing before unmarshalling*/
            }
    }
```

the Response filter is:-

public class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

```
 @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        if (!requestContext.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("Head")) {
             /*Some processing after Marshalling*/

        }

}
```

my handler is :-

```
@POST
@Path("abc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public  Response createABC(App app){
/*lines of code*/
return Response.status(Status.CRETED).entity(abc).build();
}
```

My question is are the filters called after Marshallling and Unmarshalling,i.e is the app object created after the method AuthorizationRequestFilter and abc is Marshalled before calling of Response Filter

Answer (score 0):

The request filter is called before unmarshalling. This should be apparent, as you still have access to the entity input stream (meaning it hasn't been read from yet). You could easily test this by writing a trivial `MessageBodyReader`. Set an arbitrary header in the request filter, then you will be able to extract the same header from the readers `readFrom` method.

The response filter will be called before the marshalling. Again this could easily be tested by writing a trivial `MessageBodyWriter`. Set an arbitrary header in the filter, and you should be able to access it in the writer's `writeTo` method.

If you want to perform some operation after marshalling, you instead could use a [`WriterInterceptor`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9712), which wraps the call the writer's marshalling method. For example

```
@Provider
public class SimpleIntercetor implements WriterInterceptor{

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        // Processing before marshalling

        context.proceed();  // marshal

        // Processing after marshalling
    }
}
```

**Some Resources:**

- [How to Write Custom Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6720)
- [Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9712)

The links are to Jersey documentation, but interceptors, readers, writers are standard to JAX-RS 2.0, so the documentation should be applicable to whatever implementation you're using (for the most part :-)